# Setting HDRI to effect only one specific object

Tags: modeling, hdri

Is it possible to set HDRI for one object and set a different for another object,

e.g)

HDRI A for Sphere
HDRI B for Cube

and so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HDRI is in the world settings and world settings are per scene. You can have the 2 objects in different scenes with different world settings.
Link them to a "wip" scene to see them all at once and animate easily.
Then render the two scenes as separate and overlay using depth in the compositor.